# Why is my AWS CodeDeploy revision location URL incorrect?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am building my java application using the AWS CodePipeline.  It builds and deploy s no problems.

However, when I go to CodeDeploy history and try to reuse one of the deployments it does not work because the S3 revision URL for the build artifact is incorrect.

For example, the displayed revision location URL will look something like:

```
s3://codepipeline-us-east-1-blahblah/MyApplicationName/BuildArtif/LGJUKWM.zip?eTag=XXXXXXX**
```

But the actual revision location URL is:

```
s3://codepipeline-us-east-1-blahblah/MyApplicationName/BuildArtif/LGJUKWM?eTag=XXXXXXX
```

Notice the ZIP suffix in the displayed version of the revision URL, but the actual artifact has no ZIP extension.

Is there someway to correct this?